# OpenCV error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I am new to OpenCV and am trying to make a live face tracker on my computer. I seem to be having an issue with my video input (is it not getting any?). I'm on a mac laptop and am trying to use my built-in webcam.

Error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.3.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv- 
python/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 
&& size.height>0 in function 'imshow'
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    #capture frame by frame
    ret, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('test', img)


cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

I tried to change cv2.VideoCapture(0) to cv2.VideoCapture(1), but that resulted in this error:

```
You might be loading two sets of Qt binaries into the same process. Check that all plugins 
are compiled against the right Qt binaries. Export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 and check that 
only one set of binaries are being loaded.
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x7ff06a82c5d0) is not the object's thread 
(0x7ff06a876c30).
Cannot move to target thread (0x7ff06a82c5d0)
```

Comment: First check your device manager to see if your webcam driver have installed and working fine and what kind of webcam do you use ? could you open your webcam in your OS already?

Answer (score 1):

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Check if camera opened successfully
if (cap.isOpened()== False): 
  print("Error opening video stream or file")

while(cap.isOpened()):
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  if ret == True:

    cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break

  else: 
    break

cap.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Do you know how I can open a window on my computer that shows my webcam feed? I thought that this would do that but I guess it doesn't

Comment: I run it in terminal and use Atom as my IDE

Comment: hi, try delete message here ;), for me with terminal it's work, and for vscode i need start in an administrator from terminale like : sudo /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron